# HighCharts: Tooltip is not visible in Bar chart for very small value

Tags: highcharts

HighCharts: Tooltip is not visible in Bar chart for very small value 
e.g. 
If we have 2 columns, one has value 5000 and another has 1 then we are not able to see the bar for value 1 and tooltip for corresponding value is also not visible. Is there any provision to show the toolptip for all columns in Bar chart irrespective of column values?

Comment: Can you add your code example? have you tried reading http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can check the mouse y position if it is between top/bottom bar and call the tooltip programmatically. Maybe if the differences are big, so you should use more axes with different scales. Anyway, the solution depends on a specific case so you should set up a live example on jsfiddle/codepen/etc. or paste the code you use.

Answer (score 1):

If it works for your case, you can use a shared tooltip. This will display a tooltip whenever your mouse is in the column/bar area but will have all series values in the tooltip.

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5gu8mor7/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the minPointLength to see the small values

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            minPointLength: 10
        }
    }
```

you can set set it to smaller values, if you want those bars smaller

here is a full fiddle with how it works http://jsfiddle.net/tru0psqL/